# How to left align the description of an equation?

Tags: equations, alignment

Somebody can help me left align the description of an equation numbering just the equation. This is my code and I'm attaching an image of how should it looks.[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mutavel}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
%\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx} % <---- these are needed

\begin{document}
\subsection{Определение коэффициента лобового сопротивления самолёта при нулевой подъёмной силе на высоте крейсерского полёта и докритического числа Маха}
Минимальное сопротивление самолёта определяется по формуле:
\begin{equation}
    c_{xa min} = \frac{K_\textup{з}}{S}\bigg(C_\textup{xa кр}S_\textup{кр}+C_\textup{xa го}S_\textup{го}+C_\textup{xa во}S_\textup{во}+C_\textup{xa ф}S_\textup{м.ф}+\sum_{j=1}^{m} (N_\textup{мг j}C_\textup{xa мг j}S_\textup{м.мг j}+N_\textup{пил j}C_\textup{xa пил j}S_\textup{м.пил j})\bigg);
    \label{eq:c_xa0}
\end{equation}
где
\begin{flalign*}
    K_\textup{з} - \textup{коэффициент запаса, учитывающий неучтённые данной методикой факторы, и принимаемый равным значению 1,05};\\
    C_\textup{xa кр},C_\textup{xa ф},C_\textup{xa го},C_\textup{xa во},C_\textup{xa мг},C_\textup{xa пил}- \textup{коэффициенты минимального лобового сопротивления крыла, фюзеляжа, горизонтального, вертикального оперения, одной мотогондолы двигателя, одного пилона двигателя соответственно};\\
    m - \textup{количество типов мотогондол на самолёте}; \\
    N_\textup{мг j} - \textup{количество мотогондол двигателя данного типа}; \\
    S,S_\textup{кр},S_\textup{м.ф},S_\textup{го},S_\textup{во},S_\textup{м.мг},S_\textup{м.пил} - \textup{площади соответственно: крыла, консолей крыла (без подфюзеляжной части), фюзеляжа, горизонтального, вертикального оперения, одной мотогондолы данного типа, одного пилона данного типа}.
\end{flalign*}
```

Comment: Your MWE has not contain showed formula nor explanation of the meaning of its variable ...

Answer (score 5):

I'd define a suitable command for such descriptions.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mutavel} % https://github.com/protsenkovi/latex-ssau-gost-style/blob/master/mutavel.sty

%\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
%\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx} % <---- these are needed

\newcommand{\tsub}[1]{_{\text{\normalfont #1}}}
\newcommand{\where}[1]{%
  \hspace*{\fill}%
  \parbox[b]{\textwidth-\widthof{где }}{%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{где }\ignorespaces#1%
  }\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}%
}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Определение коэффициента лобового сопротивления самолёта при 
  нулевой подъёмной силе на высоте крейсерского полёта и докритического числа Маха}

Минимальное сопротивление самолёта определяется по формуле:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:c_xa0}
\begin{split}
c\tsub{xa min} = 
  \frac{K\tsub{з}}{S}\biggl(&
    C\tsub{xa кр}S\tsub{кр}+C\tsub{xa го}S\tsub{го}+
    C\tsub{xa во}S\tsub{во}+C\tsub{xa ф}S\tsub{м.ф}\\
    &+\sum_{j=1}^{m} (N\tsub{мг $j$}C\tsub{xa мг $j$}S\tsub{м.мг $j$}+
                    N\tsub{пил $j$}C\tsub{xa пил $j$}S\tsub{м.пил $j$})
  \biggr);
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\where{
  $K\tsub{з}$ -
    коэффициент запаса, учитывающий неучтённые данной методикой факторы, и принимаемый 
    равным значению 1,05;
  \\
  $C\tsub{xa кр}$, $C\tsub{xa ф}$, $C\tsub{xa го}$, $C\tsub{xa во}$,
  $C\tsub{xa мг}$, $C\tsub{xa пил}$ - 
    коэффициенты минимального лобового сопротивления крыла, фюзеляжа, горизонтального, 
    вертикального оперения, одной мотогондолы двигателя, одного пилона двигателя 
    соответственно;
  \\
  $m$ -
    количество типов мотогондол на самолёте;
  \\
  $N\tsub{мг $j$}$ -
    количество мотогондол двигателя данного типа;
  \\
  $S$, $S\tsub{кр}$, $S\tsub{м.ф}$, $S\tsub{го}$, 
  $S\tsub{во}$, $S\tsub{м.мг}$, $S\tsub{м.пил}$ -
    площади соответственно: крыла, консолей крыла (без подфюзеляжной части), фюзеляжа, 
    горизонтального, вертикального оперения, одной мотогондолы данного типа, одного
    пилона данного типа.
}

Определение коэффициента лобового сопротивления самолёта при нулевой подъёмной силе 
на высоте крейсерского полёта и докритического числа Маха
Определение коэффициента лобового сопротивления самолёта при нулевой подъёмной силе 
на высоте крейсерского полёта и докритического числа Маха
Определение коэффициента лобового сопротивления самолёта при нулевой подъёмной силе 
на высоте крейсерского полёта и докритического числа Маха
(mock text for showing spaces)

\end{document}
```

Note how subscripts are input: better using a dedicated command; in the subscripts, `j` denotes a math variable, so it should be `$j$`.

[image]

Comment: I have deleted my answer and upvote your "*supreme*" answer. I not know the cyrillic language :-).

Comment: Where to obtain `mutavel` package? It seems that it is not on CTAN.

Comment: @Zarko I just googled for `mutavel.sty`. Added the URL

Comment: @egreg, thank you! I downloaded `mutavel` package, store it in `C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\mutavel` (I use MikTeX on W10 mashine) . Compiling your answer gives me error `I can't find file  'custom-math.tex'`. Where to find this file? Google didn't give me anything usable.

Comment: @Zarko It sits one level above in the same GitHub site

Comment: @egreg That worked really well! Its the second time that you saved me. I noticed that you used "split". Doing this gives different results than using "align"?

Comment: @OscarEspinosa Yes, look at the placement of the equation number.